# How to write `console.log()` calls to Firefox's `stdout` or `stderr`?

Tags: logging, firefox, browser

I'm trying to figure out how to configure Firefox such that all `console.log()` calls by visited websites are written to Firefox's `stdout` or `stderr`.
I already achieved this for Chrome using the CLI flags `--enable-logging`, `--v=1` and `--log-level=0`.

According to [Firefox documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/networking/http/logging.html), the environment variables `MOZ_LOG` and `MOZ_LOG_FILE` should be set to configure logging.
However, I have not found a setting where `console.log()` calls are logged.
I've already tried setting these variables as indicated below, which are examples found in the aforementioned documentation and in a [StackExchange answer](https://superuser.com/a/1642781).

1. `MOZ_LOG=timestamp,rotate:200,nsHttp:5,cache2:5,nsSocketTransport:5,nsHostResolver:5`
2. `MOZ_LOG=all:5`

None of these seem to log `console.log()` calls however.

So I guess my questions are:

- Is it even possible to log `console.log()` calls to Firefox's `stdout` or `stderr`?
- And if so, how can this be configured?